# What's the chronology for a race condition mentioned in [Concurrency in practice 7.2.5]

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, race-condition

As Brian Goetz states: "TrackingExecutor has an unavoidable race condition that could make it yield false positives: tasks that are identified as cancelled but actually completed. This arises because the thread pool could be shut down between when the last instruction of the task executes and when the pool records the task as complete."

**TrackingExecutor:**

```
/**
 * TrackingExecutor
 * <p/>
 * ExecutorService that keeps track of cancelled tasks after shutdown
 *
 * @author Brian Goetz and Tim Peierls
 */
public class TrackingExecutor extends AbstractExecutorService {
    private final ExecutorService exec;
    private final Set<Runnable> tasksCancelledAtShutdown =
            Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Runnable>());

    public TrackingExecutor(ExecutorService exec) {
        this.exec = exec;
    }

    public void shutdown() {
        exec.shutdown();
    }

    public List<Runnable> shutdownNow() {
        return exec.shutdownNow();
    }

    public boolean isShutdown() {
        return exec.isShutdown();
    }

    public boolean isTerminated() {
        return exec.isTerminated();
    }

    public boolean awaitTermination(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)
            throws InterruptedException {
        return exec.awaitTermination(timeout, unit);
    }

    public List<Runnable> getCancelledTasks() {
        if (!exec.isTerminated())
            throw new IllegalStateException(/*...*/);
        return new ArrayList<Runnable>(tasksCancelledAtShutdown);
    }

    public void execute(final Runnable runnable) {
        exec.execute(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    runnable.run();
                } finally {
                    if (isShutdown()
                            && Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
                        tasksCancelledAtShutdown.add(runnable);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then he creates Crawler which uses `TrackingExecutor`:

**crawler:**

```
/**
 * WebCrawler
 * <p/>
 * Using TrackingExecutorService to save unfinished tasks for later execution
 *
 * @author Brian Goetz and Tim Peierls
 */
public abstract class WebCrawler {
    private volatile TrackingExecutor exec;
    @GuardedBy("this") private final Set<URL> urlsToCrawl = new HashSet<URL>();

    private final ConcurrentMap<URL, Boolean> seen = new ConcurrentHashMap<URL, Boolean>();
    private static final long TIMEOUT = 500;
    private static final TimeUnit UNIT = MILLISECONDS;

    public WebCrawler(URL startUrl) {
        urlsToCrawl.add(startUrl);
    }

    public synchronized void start() {
        exec = new TrackingExecutor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
        for (URL url : urlsToCrawl) submitCrawlTask(url);
        urlsToCrawl.clear();
    }

    public synchronized void stop() throws InterruptedException {
        try {
            saveUncrawled(exec.shutdownNow());
            if (exec.awaitTermination(TIMEOUT, UNIT))
                saveUncrawled(exec.getCancelledTasks());
        } finally {
            exec = null;
        }
    }

    protected abstract List<URL> processPage(URL url);

    private void saveUncrawled(List<Runnable> uncrawled) {
        for (Runnable task : uncrawled)
            urlsToCrawl.add(((CrawlTask) task).getPage());
    }

    private void submitCrawlTask(URL u) {
        exec.execute(new CrawlTask(u));
    }

    private class CrawlTask implements Runnable {
        private final URL url;

        CrawlTask(URL url) {
            this.url = url;
        }

        private int count = 1;

        boolean alreadyCrawled() {
            return seen.putIfAbsent(url, true) != null;
        }

        void markUncrawled() {
            seen.remove(url);
            System.out.printf("marking %s uncrawled%n", url);
        }

        public void run() {
            for (URL link : processPage(url)) {
                if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
                    return;
                submitCrawlTask(link);
            }
        }

        public URL getPage() {
            return url;
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't understand what is the exact chronology of calls of runnable.run(), exec.shutdownNow(), exec.awaitTermination(...), exec.getCancelledTasks(), tasksCancelledAtShutdown.add(runnable), the runnable completion and thread-interleaving, which leads to a race condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I understand it. For example,`TrackingExecutor` is shutting down before `CrawlTask` exit, this task may be also recorded as a `taskCancelledAtShutdown`, because `if (isShutdown() && Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())` in `TrackingExecutor#execute` may be true , but in fact this task has completed.

```
    private class CrawlTask implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
            for (URL link : processPage(url)) {
                if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
                    return;
                submitCrawlTask(link);
            }
            // May be here, trackingExecutor is shutting down. 
            // Actually this task has completed now.But this method did not exit.
        }

    }

    public void execute(final Runnable runnable) {
        exec.execute(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    runnable.run();
                } finally {
                    // isShutdown() && Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() may be true
                    if (isShutdown()
                            && Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
                        tasksCancelledAtShutdown.add(runnable);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to be truth. 1. shutdownNow() is called on a slow core, which sends .interrupt() to all running Tasks.

Comment: 2. runnable.run() is a long-lasting method, so it cannot complete in a very short time, but Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() status becomes true.

Comment: 3. runnable.run completes and its thread switches out just before `finally` of TrackingExecutor.execute(), leaving its context.

Comment: 4. WebCrawler.stop() goes on on a slow core and exec.awaitTermination(TIMEOUT, UNIT) is called, which returns true, since runnable.run() has been completed.

Comment: 5. TrackingExecutor.execute() thread context activates again and tasksCancelledAtShutdown.add(runnable) is called, which is obviously wrong, since runnable was completed, not cancelled. Finally, saveUncrawled(exec.getCancelledTasks()) proceeds with wrong task list.

Comment: How about in the CrawlTask runnable, the final line will clear the interrupted status of the thread, then it should not have this problem anymore.